# O que abrange "desenvolvimento de software"?

Tags: debate, suporte

Recentemente tive está pergunta fechada: [Ferramenta gratuita para wireframe de aplicativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229733/ferramenta-gratuita-para-wireframe-de-aplicativo) com o motivo:

- "Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda."

Porém lendo as regras definidas na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), este deixa bem claro em uma de suas regras:

- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software

Sou apenas eu que acho que muitas vezes aqui são tratados como "desenvolvimento de software" apenas aquilo que diz respeito a programação?

Por que pra mim "desenvolvimento de software" envolve desde toda a etapa de engenharia até a construção.

Comment: Sua pergunta é um pedido de ferramenta e não um problema de "desenvolvimento de software", ou seja é off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sua pergunta é um pedido/indicação de software e falando sobre o item que você citou:

> problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software

- Problemas práticos de desenvolvimento de software:

  > Creio que seria algo como entender funcionamento de uma tecnologia e/ou erros ao compilar e/ou depurar.
- Problemas bem definidos:

  > Um problema claro, como sendo o mesmo sobre entender o funcionamento e erros no desenvolvimento

Se o seu problema fosse sobre o uso do *um software voltado para programação* em questão, por exemplo:

> *Ao criar o diagrama no draw.io ocorre o problema XYZ?*

então provavelmente seria **on-topic**, mas não é sobre o **uso** então é off-topic.

Em lugar algum encontrei algo que afirme que perguntas sobre "indicações" são on-topic e por experiencia própria de 4 anos no site lhe digo é off-topic, se abrir espaço para algo como isto também será possível abrir espaço para coisas um tanto quanto absurdas como alguém chegar e perguntar:

> Qual o melhor monitor (display/ecrã) para não cansar minhas vistas enquanto programo? E com um bom preço

Não é on-topic e jogar no meio da pergunta que usará isto para programação não o torna on-topic.

O foco do site é:

- Perguntas sobre um código e/ou tecnologia que você esta usando.
- O uso de uma ferramenta existente voltada para programação

Volta e meia é lógico que abrimos espaço para outros tipos de perguntas como:

- [User-experience](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux), claro que dentro do contexto de desenvolvimento visual
- [Licenciamento de softwares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licen%C3%A7a)

Mas isto porque elas são extremamente úteis e atingem muitas pessoas por ser algo que é muito relacionado ao desenvolvimento e geralmente segue uma longa explicação com detalhamentos, já indicações de software e serviços não seguem com orientações, ficam geralmente mais para um monte de amontoados de comentários no campo de resposta, um exemplo é a resposta do [@Diego](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229734/3635) na sua própria pergunta, soa mais como algo promocional: `ótimo, free, flexível, etc`

Tem quem goste, mas realmente eu acho que no máximo isso caberia como um comentário e **não** como resposta.

### Onde posso pedir por indicações de software e serviços?

No CHAT:

> [(Estouro de Pilha - `(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻`)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

- É um lugar para trocarmos ideias
- tem um bom numero de frequentadores
- tem regras também, mas são de comportamento.
- Não é um lugar para obrigatoriamente ninguém lhe ajudar, mas não custa nada pedir indicações lá

Outro lugar para perguntar é o (inglês):

> [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Apesar de estar em inglês, hoje com google tradutor e um breve conhecimento de inglês é fácil solicitar algo. É importante notar que lá pode-se fazer um pedido, mas é recomendado que se tenha uma certa qualidade ao perguntar:

- [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/33613)

Assim como no momento de responder:

- [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/33613)

Comment: Porque o -1? Falei algo errado, se sim por favor, me explique aonde errei para melhorar.

Answer (score 4):

> Sou apenas eu que acho que muitas vezes aqui são tratados como
>   "desenvolvimento de software" apenas aquilo que diz respeito a
>   programação?
>
> Por que pra mim "desenvolvimento de software" envolve desde toda a
>   etapa de engenharia até a construção.

Concordo que desenvolvimento de software seja mais que apenas programação/código. E sim, tem gente que acha que o site é só para perguntas sobre código, a ponto de reclamarem da falta de código em perguntas conceituais.

A sua pergunta, porém, cai num caso mais particular, de pedido de recomendação de ferramenta. Esse tipo de pedido é controverso aqui desde o início do site, e já era controverso antes disso no próprio Stack Overflow original, tanto que acabaram criando um site na rede especificamente para isso (mas todo em inglês). Não vou entrar no mérito da questão, mas se quiserem debater isso fiquem à vontade, aqui mesmo ou em outro debate aqui no meta.

Em resumo, concordo com a sua definição de desenvolvimento de software, mas não acho que a sua pergunta tenha sido fechada por causa de um entendimento errado dessa definição. Infelizmente as mensagens de fechamento de perguntas nem sempre explicam bem o que houve. Dá pra tentarmos melhorar, mas mesmo assim não tem como explicações padronizadas atenderem satisfatoriamente a todos os casos específicos. No seu caso, a mensagem nem menciona o motivo real do fechamento.